# Draw a rectangle around specific panel in base graphics R

Tags: r, graphics, purrr

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a specific panel, say panel number 2 (or (1, 2))

If I try to use `box()` it will draw on the last panel that was plotted.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
purrr::map(1:4, function(x) plot(data=mtcars, cyl~mpg))
box(lty = '1373', col = 'red', lwd=6)
```

[image]

> Is there a way to tell `box` to plot to a specific panel or to call `box` at certain `map` iteration number?

Comment: Can't add answer anymore, but in your specific case, withing `map` call, change your `plot` call to `plot(cyl ~ mpg, data = mtcars, bty = ifelse(.x == 3, 'n', 'o'))`. After the `map`, to focus on plot 3 (you can choose any of them) add `par(mfg = c(nr = 2, nc = 1))`. And after that call your `box` function. I changed it from plot 4 in your example, to plot 3 to make an example more general.

Comment: @utubun YES ! the `par(mfg = c(nr = 2, nc = 1))` was what I needed ! I just plugged the correct coordinates after the `purrr::map` call and *presto* (no need for the `ifelse(...)` in my case). I understand why it got marked as a duplicate but I think it should be removed (and you should be able to provide the answer!)

Comment: Glad I can help

Answer (score 1):

The things you are iterating over are passed as argument to your function, in your case the anonymous function with argument `x`. Hence you can use `x` in your function to decide how to draw the box.

For example:

```
## write a function rather than an anonymous one - easier but not needed
bfun <- function(x) { 
    plot(data=mtcars, cyl~mpg, bty = 'n') 
    if(x == 4) { 
        box(lty = '1373', col = 'red', lwd = 6 ) 
    } else { 
        box() 
    } 
}

purrr::map(1:4, bfun)
```

This produces

[image]

You can include whatever logic you want in the function that does the plotting to decide how to draw the box.

Comment: Yes, I *could* incorporate this into `f(x)`. I guess my toy example is not awesome for this. My real life `x` is used by the function (not an anonymous one, a 300 lines one), so I would need to iterate something else like (something in the form of the number of iterations like `1:length(x)`). I was trying not to add more stuff to `f(x)` which is already substantial (and happens to plot something)